# A check box on select should select all other check boxes present in the table column

Tags: checkbox, datatables, selectall

I am using data tables. I need to have a check box which on selection selects all other check boxes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: which datatable? can you share some reference or code?

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://datatables.net/reference/button/selectAll)

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        'selectAll',
        'selectNone'
    ],
    language: {
        buttons: {
            selectAll: "Select all items",
            selectNone: "Select none"
        }
    }
} );
```